# Possible to clear the LINQPad results window with code?

Tags: linqpad

Using LINQPad, using the extension method Dump(), Console.WriteLine or Debug.Writeline, the values will appear in the results window.

Is there a way to clear this results window during the run of a linqpad script?  As an example, I tried Console.Clear() however this throws an exception

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I've added a feature to do this

```
Util.ClearResults();
```

Comment: How about implementing a progress spinner writing to the console ? I tried to do a Console.Write and Console.Clear() which gave an error. Switching to Util.ClearResults in a tight loop with Thread.Sleep of 100 ms between each iteration to "rotate" the console spinner, gave no output at all using Util.ClearResults ..

Comment: LINQPad lets you dump progress bars: http://share.linqpad.net/rx7h34.linq . You can implement a spinner as follows: http://share.linqpad.net/av2a4w.linq

Comment: For the second snippet (spinner one), I got `'Util' does not contain a definition for 'HtmlHead'` error message. Seems like the second snippet only works on `v7.x`